# What is the Crypto in Metaverse

Tags: blockchain, currencies

When I read about the Metaverse in today's crypto space, I think of Second Life and my understanding is that Metaverse as used in today's crypto space is basically Second Life with VR but this looks too straightforward to cause so much excitement as seen in the crypto community that I think I'm missing something important. Why do we need crypto for in Metaverse projects?

Answer (score 1):

'Metaverse' seems like a buzzword these days, but to answer you question quite generally:

The invention of the internet allowed humanity to find all sorts of new ways to share and exchange information. We keep creating more and more ways to share more and more data, and perhaps AR/VR/metaverse tech will help continue this in the future.

The invention of bitcoin is similar in my opinion, in that it will allow humanity to engage in all sorts of new ways to share and transact value. So it seems plausible that some of the experiences that you could have in the 'metaverse' could warrant an exchange of value between the participants.

To simply build/engage with the metaverse, there certainly is no 'crypto' token required, technically speaking. But if metaverse users want to transact, it seems reasonable to assume that they might do so using something like bitcoin (ie, an open and secure network, that operates independently of the metaverse itself). Having the option to enable a digital economy via an open monetary network is something fairly new and novel, so it is difficult to predict what the future might look like. Who could have predicted how popular an app like instagram would be, back in the early 90s? Only time will tell how it all plays out.